# Segmentation Fault help, rookie mistake?

Tags: c, program-entry-point

this is a school assignment.

The essential problem is to take a large array of numbers, implement multiple different kinds of shell sorts on it, analyze the complexity, and so on.

I have a shell sort written using selection sort (I know it's inefficient, that's the point)
but I am having trouble testing it.

My main file is called sorting_main.c and the function defs are in sorting.c.

I compile and then run it using these commands.

```
gcc -Werror -Wall -Wshadow -O3 sorting.c sorting_main.c -o proj1
```

When the project is finished, I will be able to use this command to run it...

```
./proj1 s input.txt seq.txt output.txt
```

I can run it now though, with just ./proj1 in the terminal if I manually define testing parameters in my main. This is where I am stuck, I don't know if I am doing something wrong in making stuff up to test or if my implementations are fatally flawed. 
And my goal is to test my selection sort...
Here is my main:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

//Function Declarations////
long *Load_File(char *Filename, int *Size);
int Save_File(char *Filename, long *Array, int Size);
void Shell_Insertion_Sort(long *Array, int Size, double *N_Comp, double *N_Move);
void Shell_Selection_Sort(long *Array, int Size, double *N_Comp, double *N_Move);
int Print_Seq(char *Filename, int Size);


int main()
{



long int  *Array[11];
 *Array[0]=9;
 *Array[1]=80;
 *Array[2]=4;
 *Array[3]=1;
 *Array[4]=5;
 *Array[5]= 3;
 *Array[6]= 7;
 *Array[7]=15;
 *Array[8]= 9;
 *Array[9]= 5;
 Shell_Selection_Sort(Array[10],11,0,0);
 /*
 int i = 0;
 for(i=0;i<=10;i++)
   {
     printf("%li\n",*Array[i]);
   }
 */
  return 0;
}
```

Again, I compile using this command in the terminal:

```
gcc -Werror -Wall -Wshadow -O3 sorting.c sorting main.c -o proj1
```

Where I receive only 2 warnings saying that I have not used a calculated value yet (which is expected)

And then I run using this:

```
./proj1
```

Does anyone see any reasons that I would receive a segfault in

```
#0  0x000000000040096b in Shell_Selection_Sort ()
#1  0x00000000004005d7 in main ()
```

I feel like this should be a simple mistake...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're declaring an array of pointers.

Either declare an array or a pointer (if you declare a pointer, you need to malloc some memory).

In your case you should declare an array.

```
long Array[11];
```

Store elements like this

```
Array[2]=4;
Array[3]=1;
```

`long Array[11]` has the signature of `long *Array`, so it will compile with the function you're calling.

Now as for those `double *` arguments, you're going to have to write some comparison functions...

Comment: Hahaha I knew this would be some ridiculous mistake that I should've never made in the first place.....thank you!!!! Pointers are still a sore weak point of mine...

Comment: Another question...I changed the array definition as you indicated. However, I still have an issue...I receive the same error. Is it because of the double* arguments you mentioned? can I not just pass 0 into those for now until I have them set up?

Comment: Those aren't going to be pointers to doubles. They're pointers to a function that returns doubles.